# How to plot classification contours on 2 features out of 4 in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, neural-network, supervised-learning

I have written a neural network to classify the **Iris dataset** and I want to plot the decision boundary and contours.

When I select 2 features (2nd and 4th columns) out of 4 and feed it to the network, I can plot it easily and it looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that when I feed all 4 features to the network, I can't plot the contours.

To resolve this, I tried to train the network on all 4 features, then replace columns 1 and 3 and plot the remaining data, but that doesn't give any meaningful plot.

What should I do?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sklearn.datasets


iris = sklearn.datasets.load_iris()

# extract 2nd and 4th columns/features from dataset
X = iris.data[:, [1, 3]]
y = iris.target

# M = number of test cases
# N = number of input features
# K = number of output labels
# L = number of layers
# S[L] = number of units in each layer

# X = [M, N] input matrix
# Y = [M, K] output matrix

# a[L] = activations for each layer
# w[L] = weights for each layer
# b[L] = biases for each layer

# d[L] = deltas for each layer
# dw[L] = weight gradients for each layer
# db[L] = bias gradients for each layer

M = y.size
K = np.unique(y).size

Y = np.zeros((M, K))
for k in range(K):
    Y[:, k] = (k == y)

L = 4
S = [2, 9, 6, K]

a = [None] * L

w = [None] * L  # w[L-1] = None
b = [None] * L  # b[L-1] = None

d = [None] * L  # d[0] = None
dw = [None] * L  # dw[L-1] = None
db = [None] * L  # dw[L-1] = None

eta = 0.001
Lambda = 0.001

np.random.seed(0)
for l in range(L-1):
    w[l] = np.random.randn(S[l], S[l + 1]) / np.sqrt(S[l])
    b[l] = np.random.randn(1, S[l + 1])
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------


ax = plt.gca()

h = 0.01
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + .5
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + .5
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------


def classify(X):
    a[0] = X

    for l in range(1, L):
        z = np.dot(a[l-1], w[l-1]) + b[l-1]
        a[l] = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

    return np.argmax(a[L-1], axis=1)


def updatePlot():
    Z = classify(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

    ax.cla()
    ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, c=y, alpha=0.75)
    ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=50)

    text = 'iteration: %05d\ncost: %.7f' % (i, cost)
    ax.text(x_max + 0.2, y_max + 0.2, text, ha='right')
    plt.pause(0.000001)


for i in range(10001):
    # ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    # FORWARD FEED
    a[0] = X

    for l in range(1, L):
        z = np.dot(a[l-1], w[l-1]) + b[l-1]
        a[l] = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
    # --------------------------------------------------

    # ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    # BACK PROPAGATION
    d[L-1] = np.copy(a[L-1])
    d[L-1][range(M), y] -= 1
    for l in range(L-2, 0, -1):
        dw[l] = (a[l].T).dot(d[l + 1]) + Lambda * w[l]
        db[l] = np.sum(d[l + 1], axis=0, keepdims=True)

        d[l] = d[l + 1].dot(w[l].T) * (a[l] * (1 - a[l]))

    dw[0] = (a[0].T).dot(d[1]) + Lambda * w[0]
    db[0] = np.sum(d[1], axis=0, keepdims=True)
    # --------------------------------------------------

    # ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    # GRADIENT DESCENT
    for l in range(L-1):
        w[l] += -eta * dw[l]
        b[l] += -eta * db[l]
    # --------------------------------------------------

    # ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    # COST CALCULATION AND PLOTTING
    if i % 100 == 0:
        loss = -np.sum(Y * np.log(a[L-1]) + (1-Y) * np.log(1 - a[L-1]))

        reg = 0
        for l in range(L-1):
            reg += np.sum(np.square(w[l]))
        reg *= Lambda / 2
        cost = 1 / M * (loss + reg)

        updatePlot()
    # --------------------------------------------------
plt.show()
```